# set position of my window to top when softkeyboard is active in android

Tags: android, virtual-keyboard, android-windowmanager

I want to manage my screen when virtual keyboard is active.Before I have 2 ideas that
1.Put the parent layout in scrollview:
      But issue here is When I run the app my layout scrolls to top when virtual keyboard is active,But No child control is working i.e.,inner scroll  view & other buttons were blocked.

2.Get the coordinates of edittext so that I will handle my window to move to the top according to the Y coordinate of eddittext.The code used Here is

```
 et.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            int x=et.getLeft();
            int y=et.getTop();


            return true;
        }
    });
```

Now I'm not getting how to this position to my window.Please anybody help me that my ideas will work or not.If not then suggest me with good idea.Thanks in Advance.

My Android SDK version is:4.2

Answer (score 1):

```
add below code to your activities onCreate() method : 

WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = getWindow().getAttributes();
lp.softInputMode = WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE;
getWindow().setAttributes(lp);

now, whenever softKeyboard appears Framework will resize activity window to fit in to available visible rectangle over softKeyboard.
```

Comment: It is disturbing my design & I want my edittext should be visible to the user.